# How I can create a txt file with specific data using batch in a specific path?

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to create 100 txt files starting from txt1 to txt100 with string data (i.e not to create an empty file) and it's doesn't matter if the data duplicate or not, I've just wanted to add some data in each file created in a specific path, so how can I do that?

Comment: With what data? the same in each? something different in each? a string pattern? Your question has already been downvoted, please try to improve it, in order to prevent further downvotes; or being closed as off topic, due to lack of detail, or any attempt at coding it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a little bit more info such as what is going in the files and what name do you need for the files.

Give this a go as a start. It should create 100 files in `C:\temp` named as `MyFile_1.txt` through to `MyFile_100.txt` and each would contain the text `Your Contents Here`

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "txtpath=C:\temp\"

for /L %%a in (1,1,100) do >>%txtpath%MyFile_%%a.txt echo Your Contents Here
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I try with changed the path and then run the batch, but there is nothing created! what is the issue?

Comment: Remove the `@echo off` line and add a new line below everything that says `pause`, then run it again to see what is not working.

Comment: I removed @echo off, but there are no words in my text contains "pause" so I tried again and still the same issue, there is nothing created.

Comment: Create the folder `C:\Temp\` then use the code I provided above without modifying the `txtpath` value to check that it works (works fine on my computer). If that works, then perhaps when you changed the value of `txtpath` you left the last `\` off? or you are trying to write them to a protected folder.... right-click and select Run As Administrator.

Comment: it's working now, thanks a lot.